# How do I send an enum to a method?

Tags: java, methods, enums, arguments

I am trying to create a game, and have an enum set to determine what screen the user is on.  I want to send what screen the user is on to a method that will set up the screen.

```
private enum Screen {START, SETTINGS, MAP, ATTACK, END};
private Screen currentScreen;

public void begin () {
    setScreen(Screen.START);
}

public void onMouseClick(Location point) {
    switch (currentScreen) {
        case (Screen.START)
            break;
        case (Screen.SETTINGS)
            break;
        case (Screen.MAP)
            break;
        case (Screen.ATTACK)
            break;
        case (Screen.END)
            break;
    }
}

public void setScreen(/*I do not know what to put here, would i put enum, or Screen*/) {
    //set up screen here
}
```

What do I use as the argument?

Comment: You would put `public void setScreen(Screen screen) {`, just as if it was a class instead of an enum.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is the same as if `Screen` were a class:

```
public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
    //set up screen here
}
```